# mysql query with conditions

Tags: mysql

Table: bookmark

```
id    asset   type   

1016  8271    asset   

1017  8272    federated

1018  8273    asset
```

Table: publish

```
asset   published_value

8271    1

8273    0
```

My expected result:

```
id    asset   published_value

1016  8271    1

1017  8272
```

**I need to print all the records except the published_value of the asset is 0.**

That is type field in bookmark contains many types such as asset and federated.

My query should print all the records from the table bookmark where the condition is published_value should not be zero.

Any help will be thankful and grateful.

Thanks in advance..

Comment: Are you sure you need to print entries where published_value IS NULL as well?

Comment: @@sll: No. In my expected result the publish_value of second row is empty. Because it's type is federated. It doesn't have any relation with publish table. Thats y i make it empty.

Comment: Ok have you tried queries which Marco and me already provided ?

Comment: Yes. I did. But there is a conflict rising. the count difference is changing between normal select query and using the below queries. checking it..

Comment: The queries are not working fine.. It doesn't bring the federated type. It's only focusing on asset type

Comment: Are you sure? I've just tried and it works for me

Comment: Maybe you want to do something different from what you're telling us? Be sure that my query and @sll's one are correct and work!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT b.id, b.asset, p.published_value
FROM bookmark b LEFT JOIN publish p
ON b.asset = p.asset
WHERE p.published_value IS NULL
      OR p.published_value > 0
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT b.id, b.assed, ISNULL(p.published_value, '')
FROM bookmark b 
LEFT JOIN publish p ON b.asset = p.asset 
WHERE p.published_value IS NULL OR p.published_value > 0
```

Comment: Oops, I've just deleted my post because I saw your code "correct" and I thought I was seeing something that didn't exist.. :)